# Android selector for ListView by setItemChecked not working in version 2.2.1

Tags: java, android, selector

I try to set colo for checked/selected row by method: listView.setItemChecked(i, true); but on Android 2.2.1 not working, color was not changed. If I use state_activated then this is only for newer version. How can I do that? Thanks.
I have selector:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">        
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/orange"/>
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Then ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listMP3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
</ListView>
```

RowView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
android:id="@+id/playerRow" android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.72"
    android:text="@string/songName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemLength"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/songLength" />
```

Comment: are u sure version 2.2.1 matters to you? http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: Yes it is Archos 70 tablet with 2.2.1 Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve problem. I removed selector and color changing programatically, like this in adapter. It's working in both version of Android 2.2 and 4.x.

```
if (list.get(position).GetSelected()) 
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange);
        else
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```